# Getting NZEC runtime error.Can't recognize the bug

Tags: java

This particular code is the solution for the problem the next palindrome in spoj.
This is the link http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/
The question mentions that the digits don't cross 1000000.So long should suffice,but still getting this error.

```
import java.util.*;

    import java.lang.*;

    import java.io.*;

    class Ideone

    {
        public static long tostr(String s,String b){

            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(s);

            String r = String.valueOf(a.reverse());

            return Long.parseLong(s+b+r);

        }

        public static long toStr(String s){

            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(s);

            String r = String.valueOf(a.reverse());

            return Long.parseLong(s+r); 

        }

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception

        {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 

    InputStreamReader(System.in));

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);

            int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            while(t-->0){

                long n = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());

                long number = n;


                int len = 0; while (number != 0) { number /= 10; len++; }

                if((len&1)==0){

                    String s = String.valueOf(n);

                    String r = s.substring(0,len/2);

                    while(true){

                        long num = toStr(r);


                        if(num == 99){
                            out.println(101);break;

                        }
                        if(num == 9999){
                            out.println(10001);break;
                        }
                        if(num == 999999){
                            out.println(1000001);break;
                        }
                        if(num>n )
                            {out.println(num);break;}
                        long m = Long.parseLong(r);
                        m++;    
                        r = String.valueOf(m);


                }
            }

            else{

                String s = String.valueOf(n);
                String r = s.substring(0,len/2);

                String b = s.substring((int)(len/2),(len/2)+1);

                if(b.equals("9")){

                    while(true){

                        if(n == 999){out.println(1001);break;}

                        if(n==99999){out.println(100001);break;}

                        if(n == 9999999){out.println(10000001);break;}

                        long num = tostr(r,b);

                        if(num>n){out.println(num);break;}

                        long m = Long.parseLong(r);

                        m++;

                        r = String.valueOf(m);
                    }
                }
                else{

        while(true){

                        long num = tostr(r,b);

                        if(num>n){out.println(num);break;}

                        long m = Long.parseLong(b);

                        m++;

                        b = String.valueOf(m);

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java `long` does not suffice.  The palindrome may be up to 1000000 **digits** long.  That is well beyond the size of a Java `long`.  Re-read the question carefully.